# Laravel REST redirect from GET to POST method in SAME controller not working

Tags: rest, laravel, controller

I am trying to support the use of EITHER GET or POST methods in my REST controller in laravel.

So, I would like to redirect ANY get requests sent to our REST controller to the POST method in the SAME controller instead.

I have tried many things, and now have returned back to basics as follows:

routes.php

`Route::resource('user', 'userController');`

userController.php

```
class userController extends \BaseController {

 public function index() {
    return Redirect::action('userController@store');
 }

 public function store() {

    echo 'yeeha!';      
 }
}
```

Performing a POST on the page works and outputs:

```
yeeha!
```

Performing a GET on the page produces:

```
Could not get any response

This seems to be like an error connecting to https://www.test.com/user. The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.
```

I have tried many different redirects and none are successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to do it is to use the routes file and just define it;

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/user', array ('as' => 'user.index', 'uses' => userController@store))
Route::post('/user', array ('as' => 'user.create', 'uses' => userController@store))
```

**Controller**

```
class userController extends \BaseController {
 public function store() {
    echo 'yeeha!';      
 }
}
```